# unexpected output in code in passing array in java

Tags: java, arrays, parameter-passing

I have been facing problems in passing array in java. The code is:

```
package input_output;

import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputOutput {
    private static Scanner sc;
    public static void main(String []args){
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        out.print("Enter the length of arrays   :\t");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        Employee[] emp = new Employee[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            out.print("\nEnter name and age of " + (i+1) + " employee   :\t");
            emp[i] = new Employee();
            emp[i].setName(sc.nextLine());
            sc.nextLine();
            emp[i].setAge(sc.nextInt());
        }

        Operation operate = new Operation(emp,n);

        operate.printOnScreen();

    }
}

class Operation{ 
    Employee []emp;
    public Operation(Employee[] emp,int n){
        this.emp=emp;
        for(Employee e: this.emp)
          e = new Employee();
    }

    public void printOnScreen() { 
        for(Employee e : emp){
            e = new Employee();
            out.println("Name:\t" + e.getName() + "\t\tAge:\t" + e.getAge() + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Employee class is a simple bean containing getter and setter methods of age and name.

The output is coming :

> Name: null
>   Age:0

What's my mistake?

---

Now I have changed the constructor to

```
public Operation(Employee[] emp, int n){
        this.emp=emp;
}
```

and removed the line:

```
e = new Employee();
```

from `PrintOnScreen()`

And the output is:

> Name:
>   Age:21

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with both `for(Employee e: this.emp) e = new Employee();`?

Comment: Please refrain from changing the question so that it renders valid answers invalid. Changing the source code with the corrected version is not right.

Comment: How about also posting the code for the `Employee` class so we can see whether the getter/setter is correctly implemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not outputting data from the array in the following code:

```
public void printOnScreen() 
{ 
    for(Employee e : emp)
    {
        e = new Employee(); // <<< THIS IS WRONG, AS e IS ALREADY SET BY LOOP!!
        out.println("Name:\t" + e.getName() + "\t\tAge:\t" + e.getAge() + "\n");
    }
}
```

This code creates a new `e` on every iteration of the loop => you're not outputting the entry from the array, but the freshly created one. The code should read

```
public void printOnScreen() 
{ 
    for(Employee e : emp)
    {
        out.println("Name:\t" + e.getName() + "\t\tAge:\t" + e.getAge() + "\n");
    }
}
```

---

Also, the following code doesn't make sense:

```
public Operation(Employee[] emp,int n){
    this.emp=emp;
    for(Employee e: this.emp)
      e = new Employee();
}
```

Why do you iterate over all the employees in `this.emp` to create new instances of `Employee` that are stored nowhere? Also, the `n` parameter is not used. This code should read:

```
public Operation(Employee[] emp)
{
    this.emp=emp;
}
```

Comment: i have done changes as u have said,, but the o/p is now:        Name:     Age:21   that means name is empty

Comment: Well, as you didn't show us the implementation of `Employee`, it is impossible for us to tell where the problem is. My best guess is that getter and setter simply don't work.

Answer (score 3):

To your second problem: (empty `name` fields)

The problem is the `sc.nextInt()` call. This reads an integer from the input stream but leaves the `carriage return` and `line feed` signs there. The next `sc.nextLine()` call will read these sign and nothing else. That way all names are filled with `\r\n`.

You can fix that in to ways:

```
public static void main(String []args){
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    out.print("Enter the length of arrays   :\t");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine(); // <-- new
    Employee[] emp = new Employee[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        out.print("\nEnter name and age of " + (i+1) + " employee   :\t");
        emp[i] = new Employee();
        emp[i].setName(sc.nextLine());
        //sc.nextLine(); // <-- removed 
        emp[i].setAge(sc.nextInt());
        sc.nextLine(); // <-- new
    }
    //..
}
```

Or

```
public static void main(String []args){
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    out.print("Enter the length of arrays   :\t");
    int n = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine()); // <-- changed
    Employee[] emp = new Employee[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        out.print("\nEnter name and age of " + (i+1) + " employee   :\t");
        emp[i] = new Employee();
        emp[i].setName(sc.nextLine());
        //sc.nextLine(); // <-- removed 
        emp[i].setAge(Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine())); // <-- changed
    }
    //..
}
```

If this solves your second problem, please accept `Thorsten Dittmar`s anwser for you main question.

Answer (score 1):

While printing data, you are printing data of new employee and not the earlier employee object that you created.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I think Array is not copying content with "=" in Java. Change in class Operation

```
this.emp=emp;
for(Employee e: this.emp)
    e = new Employee();
```

to

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    this.emp[i].setName(emp.getName());
    this.emp[i].setAge(emp.getAge());
}
```

Then change

```
operate.printOnScreen();
```

to

```
operate.printOnScreen(emp);
```

and

```
public void printOnScreen() { 
    for(Employee e : emp){
        e = new Employee();
        out.println("Name:\t" + e.getName() + "\t\tAge:\t" + e.getAge() + "\n");
    }
}
```

to

```
public void printOnScreen(Employee emp) { 
    for(Employee e : emp){
        out.println("Name:\t" + e.getName() + "\t\tAge:\t" + e.getAge() + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with array copying.

Comment: this.emp=emp; would copy the contents?

Comment: Heave you heard of references?